# Garbage collection in f2py-compiled Fortran module

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

**My question** is how does (and does it) garbage collection work for Fortran modules compiled as external modules (via f2py) and used by a Python script?

**Background**

I'm currently working on a Finite Element Program, mostly written in Python (for convenience) which uses several modules of Fortran subroutines for tasks where some loops cannot be avoided (i.e. assembly/update of the tangent stiffness matrix). This is compiled successfully using f2py ([the quick way](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/getting-started.html#the-quick-and-smart-way)) and the resulting .dll file is imported as a python module in the python script. The functions/subroutines can then be successfully called by Python.

The Fortran module is structured as below, with different subroutines using some of the global variables defined in the module and their own dummy variables as needed.

```
module mod
  integer, parameter :: iwp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15)
  real(iwp), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: points, der, matrix, jac, deriv, bee, g_coord
  real(iwp), allocatable, dimension(:) :: fun, disps
  real(iwp), allocatable, dimension(:,:,:) :: tensor
  integer, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: g_num, g_g
  integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: etype, weights
  integer :: ndof,nodf,ndim,nels,nip,nod
contains

...subroutines,functions...
```

The global variables are allocated and assigned directly from the Python script as F-contiguous numpy arrays with the correct type (probably poor style, but it works for me). ***These can be relatively large arrays and I want to make sure they are deallocated after the successful completion of the python script...***

Any other suggestions are welcome! Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there is no garbage collection in Fortran. Secondly, module data is the same a global variables, it has infinite lifetime. There is no automatic deallocation or finalization of module data.

If you want to deallocate a lot of data in one go, create a derived type (structure, class) that contains the data and create a final subroutine (destructor) for the type. Then, when needed, call the destructor from Python. Alternatively, make a proxy Python class and call the Fortran destructor from the destructor of the Python class.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer! I opted to have the Fortran subroutines operating directly on the numpy arrays without storing the information in the module.